# I want to get in the constructor of form object type of class

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do this

```
public partial class Form3 : FormBasic
{
    
    public Form3(List<student> li)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type `'List<student>'` is less accessible than method `'Form3.Form3(List<student>)'`  WindowsFormsApp1    D:\שולחן עבודה\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form3.cs   17  Active

Comment: What is FormBasic ?

Comment: Your `student` class is `private` or `internal`. Make it `public`.